# Self connection at DUB. YYZ to DUB to EDI

Tags: transit, dublin

Air Transat for first leg of flight and Ryanair for second flight.  Connection in DUB - Dublin I just received notification that my Air Transat flight is delayed and now I will have just 50 minutes to get from one to the other.  Flights were booked separately by me. Is this enough time and should I buy Ryanair security Fast track?

Comment: Do you have luggage to reclaim? Boarding gates for Ryanair flights typically close 30 mins before departure. I’m not sure even buying fast track will give you enough time to make the connection.

Comment: On what date is that? The flight scheduled to depart yesterday (24th) evening departed after midnight so is shown as departing on the 25th, and it arrived late in DUB, but that was a few hours ago. This evening's flight is currently estimated on schedule.

Comment: I do not have any checked luggage just carry on.

Comment: The flight is not until Sept 20/23 so I cannot check flight status yet.

Comment: I am also flying at the front of the plane to Dublin, so we will be off quickly

Comment: I would not have booked this close we had 1 hour and 40 minutes before the change.

Comment: Oh then not delayed, rescheduled. But that doesn't change much: one big issue in DUB is while a few gates are just next to security, many are a very very long walk away. Trying to find out which gates are likely, but for now my impression is that this is likely to be virtually impossible, especially since you have to go through passport control and security.

Comment: I did something similar last year (thankfully with plenty of time to connect), I recall the Ryanair gates were not so close and Irish customs and immigration (through which I *did* have to pass) was not so fast.

Answer (score 9):

I'm under the impression that this is virtually impossible, unless your first flight is quite early, or your second flight is quite late, which you won't know until it's probably too late.

Both flights seem to use to 100-series gates, which are quite a distance from security. The airport website says 10 minutes, but IIRC this is a bit optimistic (haven't been there in a while, though). Depends on the exact gate and how fast you walk (or run!) of course.

Since Ryanair gates close 30 minutes before departure, that would leave you 20 minutes to:

- Deplane and get to passport control (10 minutes)
- Queue and go through passport control (nobody knows)
- Go to security
- Queue and go through security (even with fast track I'm not sure I would budget less than 10 minutes, even though it may be faster)
- Get to your gate (10 minutes)

In short, you have 0 minutes for passport control and security. So unless additional time is added be either the first flight arriving early or the second flight arriving late, this is not going to happen, fast track or not.

I you run like mad people (in a busy airport, you know that's a difficult proposition) maybe you can do the trip to passport control and from security in 5 minutes each way, but you would still need to do passport control+security in less than 10 minutes. I wouldn't bet much on that.

I think the right option is to switch to a later DUB-EDI flight.

Note than even the 1h40 you had before the reschedule is quite short and does not give much margin in case of delays. The usual rule of thumb for a self-transfer, especially one which involves going through passport control and/or security, is at least 4 hours, unless the second flight is so cheap and frequent that you can just throw away your booking and get a new one for cheap **even at the last minute**, which is rarely the case.

Comment: That is what I thought.  Thank you